# improve DML operation performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This question is for SQL Server. How to improve the performance of DML operation for a table with 20 indexes? What are the options other than dropping indexes?

I'm a web developer with experience of writing SPs,functions etc.. I've little experience towards DB optimization. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on your DML and it depends on what you mean by performance.  Please give examples, and whether you mean "quickest to apply" or "least blocking while it is applied".

Comment: @Brian Please see comments in the below section.

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is to [visualize the query plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) using SQL Server Management Studio and determining the current performance bottleneck.  It is essentially the same procedure as with optimizing queries.

If this does not immediately make the next step obvious, then update your Stack Overflow question, providing details on your DML, schema, number of records, and what query plan you see.

Having 20 indexes tells very little about your environment.

Before you begin, the zeroest step is to `UPDATE STATISTICS` on the database.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned in the question that this was asked to me in the interview.

Comment: If I was interviewing you, I would be mainly watching out whether you are trying to optimize based on measurements or gut feelings; and just slightly less importantly, whether you have ever naturally needed to optimize something and what insight or techniques that experience gave you.

Comment: So, what's the verdict? What should I say?

Comment: The verdict is, if you start asking relevant additional questions, you are already scoring above anyone who starts pulling surefire recipes out of their sleeve.  "If performance and scalability of a system are important to you, the biggest mistake that you can make is to not know the actual performance and scalability characteristics of important queries, and the effect the different queries have on each other in a multiuser system."  (quoted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647793.aspx)

Comment: English is not my first language. How do you explain "you are already scoring above anyone who starts pulling surefire recipes out of their sleeve" in simple English.

Comment: Relevant questions = good.  Techniques (indexes, avoidance of unnecessary expensive features, denormalization, locking analysis, parametrization, statistics maintenance, index maintenance, HW planning) = good only if you can explain when and how they apply.  Blindly applied recipes ("refresh statistics") = suspect; you'll be questioned further.  Read the referenced article in entirety.